# Delete SQL Records Based on Derived Column Content

Tags: derived

I'm hoping someone can help me with this. I have a MS SQL table with a derived column, for date the records were imported, and need to delete records, based on the content of this column. What I need to do is delete all records from the table with a date of '2011-11-18'. Now this column is a datetime column, so it contains the time info after the date, i.e. 2011-11-18 09:29:38.000, but no matter what command I try for this:

- Delete from table where Date_Imported like '2011-11-18%'
- Delete from table where Date_Imported like '2011-11-18'
- Delete from table where Date_Imported = 2011-11-18

It comes back saying "0 rows affected", even though I know there are records with that date in the table. Any thoughts? I'd appreciate your assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the simplest way, but it should work:

```
Delete from table where
  year(Date_Imported) = 2011
  and month(Date_Imported) = 11
  and day(Date_Imported) = 18
```

See [Date and Time Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms186724%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

If you cast it to a date, your check should work.

```
DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE CAST(Date_Imported As Date) = '2011-11-18'
```